# How to do find and replace in one field based on the value in the other field?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file like this.

```
IMS00|20140101|Unix|Jan14
IMS01|20140201|Unix|Feb14
IMS02|20140301|Unix|Mar14
IMS03|20140101|Unix|Jan14
IMS04|20140201|Unix|Feb14
```

My criteria are,
if the column 1 value is `IMS00`, then column 4 value `Jan14` should be replaced with `Jan15`
if the column 1 value is `IMS01`, then column 4 value `Feb14` should be replaced with `Feb15`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is this for all rows (I.e `IMS02`, column 4 becomes `Mar15`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, for example in the code you write `IMS00` and later on refer to it as `IMS.00`, with dot. Also number of changed column should be probably `4`, not `3`. Anyway, you are probably looking for

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}$1=="IMS00"{$4="Jan15"}$1=="IMS01"{$4="Feb15"}1' file
```

The `BEGIN` block executes only once at the very beginning and sets both field separator `FS` and output field separator `OFS` to `|`. Final `1` is just to print everything.

Comment: I made those edit changes, I assume the same as you did ;)

Comment: Thanksa lot bro.It is working.Could you please explain the purpose of Begin and 1 at the end?

Comment: @M.Nehru see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^(IMS00\|.*\|).*/$1Jan15/; s/^(IMS01\|.*\|).*/$1Feb15/;' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('IMS00'):
            print line.replace('Jan14', 'Jan15')
        elif line.startswith('IMS01'):
            print line.replace('Feb14', 'Feb15')
```

This script will read each line from file, then it will check if the line starts with the given string, if so then the desired portion of the line will be replaced by the replacement string.